# Check Unhandled Exception .NET 4

Tags: exception, unhandled-exception

I would know what are the Exception that i didnt handle , even if doesn't throw any exception at the moment, in my Winform Program.

Is there a way to do with .Net 4?

I already made some research about this, but all software that i found doesnt support .NET4.

Update: I need a way to know Which are the Exception that i Didnt Handle. Just like [Exception-Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/exception-hunter/) but it doesnt support .NET 4 more.
Thanks

Edit: Updated Question

Comment: You need to provide more details...

Comment: Hehe, they finally discovered that exception specifications are useless.  This didn't change in .NET 4, it was just a convenient excuse to discontinue their product.  Don't use tools like that, they are snake oil.

Comment: Thanks , by the way i just learn a new term : Snake oil , never read it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no sure way do what you are asking, unless you never call any third-party code, including .NET framework methods. Unlike Java, .NET has no concept of "checked" exceptions. So, the only way to know with 100% certainty what exceptions a given piece of code can throw is to read the code.